# Extracting text from a file when I know its format

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, scripting

I am running a script which will output a file called scServer.scs which looks something like this:

> 49138@bber0501u29b.bb2.cluster
>
> 2
>
> Solution 1
>
> Fluid Flow (Fluent)
>
> Solution
>
> Transient Structural
>
> 7443_bber0501u29b.bb2.cluster
>
> 27412@lic-server1.abc.ac.uk

Later in the script I need to reference the "49138" and "bber0501u29b.bb2.cluster" but they will be different every time I run the script. So after my script generates scServer.scs I need to extract those pieces of text and write them as variables?

Comment: is the data always on line 1? or the first one in the format of user@host? How do we know it's the right data?

Comment: It is always in that format, always on line 1, I belive RoVo has the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  your data is always in the first line and in format user@domain, you can do this:

Extract the first line and use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
firstline=$(head -n1 file)
user=${firstline%@*}
domain=${firstline##*@}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using read and awk:

```
read -r user domain < <(awk -F\@ 'NR==1{print $1,$2}' scServer.scs)
```

Will extract the first line of `scServer.scs` and separate two fields using `@` as the field separator, assign the first field to the `user` variable and the second to the `domain` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
g=`awk -F "@" 'NR==1{print $1}' filename `
y=`awk -F "@" 'NR==1{print $NF}' filename `


praveen@praveen:/tmp$ echo $g
49138
praveen@praveen:/tmp$ echo $y
bber0501u29b.bb2.cluster
```